# Silverlight Binding to UserControl's DependencyProperty throws NullReferenceException

Tags: c#, silverlight, binding, user-controls, dependency-properties

I have a `UserControl` with a dependency property named `ItemWidth`. I'm going to bind width of several Path in the `UserControl` to this dependency property through a `Style` but at design time I get NullReferenceException. Here is the code:

MyUserControl.xaml.cs

```
public partial class MyUserControl: UserControl
{
    public MyUserControl()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    public double ItemWidth
    {
        get { return (double )GetValue(ItemWidthProperty);}
        set { SetValue(ItemWidthProperty, value);}
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty ItemWidthProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("ItemWidth", typeof(double),
        typeof(MyUserControl), new PropertyMetadata(21));
```

MyUserControl.xaml

```
<UserControl x:Name = "root" ....>
    <StackPanel DataContext="{Binding ElementName=root}"
        Orientation="Horizontal">
        <StackPanel.Resources>
            <Style TargetType="Path">
                <Setter Property="Width" Value="{Binding ItemWidth}"/>
            </Style>
        </StackPanel.Resources>
        <Path Data="some path"/>
        <Path Data="some path"/>
        <Path Data="some path"/>
        <Path Data="some path"/>
        <Path Data="some path"/>
    </StackPanel> 
</UserControl>
```

If I set the width for each Path separately no error occurs. But I want to use styles and do not define width property for every Path in the `UserControl`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem is with PropertyMetadata Initialization ,its casting 21 to integer.

if you use

```
new PropertyMetadata(21d)
```

or

```
new PropertyMetadata(21.00)
```

it will not throw null exception.

Comment: Is it true to use double as dependencyproperty and use it to bind it to `Width` & `Height` property?